# Rust reqwest: How to get local and remote SockAddr?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I want to get local/remote `SockAddr` pair of a successful reqwest http connection.

I used to write the following code.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), anyhow::Error> {
    let response = reqwest::Client::new()
        .get("https://example.com/")
        .send()
        .await?
        .error_for_status()?;

    let http_info = response
        .extensions()
        .get::<hyper::client::connect::HttpInfo>()
        .ok_or(anyhow::anyhow!("failed to collect socket addresses"))?;

    println!("sock_local_addr: {}", http_info.local_addr());
    println!("sock_remote_addr: {}", http_info.remote_addr());
    println!("response text: {}", response.text().await?);

    Ok(())
}
```

In case of old reqwest and hyper (reqwest==0.11, hyper==0.14), it works well.

But latest hyper does not have `hyper::client::connect::HttpInfo`, and reqwest 0.11 is a little stale.

Is there any proper way to get local/remote socket addresses in latest reqwest version?

---

In case of reqwest 0.12,

```
response
    .extensions()
    .get::<hyper::client::connect::HttpInfo>()
```

does not return `Some::<HttpInfo>`, but returns `None` (it can not get SocketAddr).

Comment: `reqwest` is a rust crate.

Comment: Please don't include the answer in the question. Instead you can answer your own question using the form below.

Comment: @Jmb Don't delete my edit. It is not an answer.Returnin None means it could not get SocketAddrs.

Comment: Request. The word is 'request'. Not 'reqwest'. You spelt it correctly in your code: why not to us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in hyper's [Upgrade from v0.14 to v1](https://hyper.rs/guides/1/upgrading/) guide:

> #### `Client`
>
> The higher-level pooling `Client` was removed from hyper 1.0. A similar type was added to [`hyper-util`](https://crates.io/crates/hyper-util), called [`client::legacy::Client`](https://docs.rs/hyper-util/latest/hyper_util/client/legacy/struct.Client.html). It’s mostly a drop-in replacement.

You'll find [`hyper_util::client::legacy::connect::HttpInfo`](https://docs.rs/hyper-util/latest/hyper_util/client/legacy/connect/struct.HttpInfo.html) in there too.

Comment: Thanks, It works! I did checked CHANGELOG.md on github, but did not checked the upgrade guide.